# Nested if-else statement in C doesn't work

Tags: c, if-statement

TASK: A hotel room costs nothing if you are 60 years old, if you are under 10 years old it costs £5. For everyone else is £30 plus an additional £10 if you weigh more than 20 stone.

Write a C program that reads the customer's age first, then the weight, and then outputs the costs they need to pay.

Here is my code: The nested if-else statement doesn't work, it seems to be stuck after reading the first if statement, it ignores the options of age >= 10 or age <10, all the outputs are 0.

What is wrong? Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void){

    int age;
    int weight;
    
    scanf ("%d %d", &age, &weight);

    int overweight = weight > 20;
    int underweight = weight <= 20;
 
    if (age = 60) {
        printf ("0\n");
        
    } else if (age >=10  && overweight) {
        printf ("40\n");

    } else if (age >= 10 && underweight) {
        printf ("30\n");
       
    } else if (age < 10) {
        printf ("5\n");
    }    
          return 0;
}
```

Comment: `age = 60` is an _assignment_. Use `==` for comparison

Comment: if (age = 60) performs an assigment, not a comparison

Comment: Would suggest posting the above comments as answers.

Comment: How much does a room cost if you're 61 years old? Or 70?

Comment: @ AdrianMole Only exact age of 60 is for free. Under 10s is £5. Everyone else is £30.

Comment: @ Mat @ Dooggy Thank you both! You've solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (age = 60)` here you perform an assignment, not a comparison.
`if (age == 60)` will compare if age is equal to 60.

Check comparison operators here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer: age = 60 is an assignment, Not comparison. It should be if (age == 60).

Thanks to Mat & Dooggy's comment.